# How can I expand values of an approximation in series form in vicinity of points?

Tags: taylor-expansion, classical-mechanics

I have recently switched from experimental structural engineering to more theoretical subjects (mechanics) and that is why my question may sound simple to you.

My question: How can I expand values of the approximation below in series form in vicinity of points $ r = R+h $ and $ z_0 = t_3$?$$
K_{rr} = σ_{rr} \left(1 + \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial r} \right) + σ_{rz} \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial z}.
$$
It will help me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: So, as I understood, you want to approximately calculate the value of $K_{rr}$, right? And you need to calculate the partial derivatives of $u_r$. Do you know anything about the function $u_r = u_r(r, z)$?

Comment: Yes I want to calculate value of $ K_rr $. The function $ u_r $ is shown in detail in the attached picture. 

Thanks.

Comment: What attached picture? And instead of pictures, please try to use written out equations (in the style of the edit that I made to your post). They are clearer and don't require going to a different page.

Comment: Yes I want to calculate value of $ K_rr $. The function $ u_r $ is shown in detail in the attached picture. 
$ u_i = \sum_{q=0}^\infinity \epsilon^q u_i^q = \epsilon^0 u_i^0 +  \epsilon^1 u_i^1 + .... $
Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry. I am new. Still learning how to write them in the specified form.

Comment: Is it clearer now?

Comment: Still, the goal is to calculate some value or approximation of partial derivatives of $u_r$. And you have said that it consists of a sum of other terms. Do you know anything else about $u$? Because the sum you gave doesn't really help in determining any partial derivatives.

Comment: No that is all what I know for now. After getting expression for $K_{rr}$ I will have to put it in the boundary condition $$K_{rr} n_r + K_{zr} n_z = 0$$ to verify the boundary conditions.